# Cannot configure Python 3.5 to use Visual C++ compiler on Windows

Tags: python, windows, configuration, python-3.5

When I was using Python 3.4 I used MinGW to compile modules. Unfortunately in 3.5 MinGW support no longer works. I've installed the correct Visual C++ stuff, but `pip` still tries to use the MinGW compiler and fails.

How do I tell it to use the correct compiler?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I bought a new computer that didn't have the problem. So there's your solution.

Comment: `"I fixed my car's air conditioning by buying a new car."`

Comment: @Siyual More like "I couldn't figure out how to turn off the right turn signal, but buying a new car seems to have fixed that." That computer had other weird problems with Python though, I think it was a side-effect of the hard drive beginning to die.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

- Install [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146) with C++ checked
- Make sure [environment variable](http://www.devdungeon.com/content/fix-pip-install-unable-find-vcvarsallbat) for VS is set
- In `PYTHONPATH\Lib\distutils` dir create (or edit) file `distutils.cfg` with following lines:

```
[build]
compiler=msvc
```